# To delete string contents from file using python list

Tags: python, string, list, file

Using python, I was trying to remove string content from input_file, so in my `delete_list` I was passing `"*.sh"`.

what should have been passed to remove strings from file to my `delete_list` to remove string values from file.

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

infile = "input_file"
outfile = "expected_file"

delete_list = ["*.sh"]
with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)
```

input_file

```
papaya.sh   10
Moosumbi.sh 44
jackfruit.sh 15
orange.sh 11
banana.sh 99
grapes.sh 21
dates.sh 6
```

expected_file

```
10
44
15
11
99
21
6
```

Comment: Is the problem really to remove a set of strings, or is the problem really just to "print the second column"?  That's a much easier problem, and probably doesn't even need Python.

Comment: @TimRoberts printing second column will also work. But i was trying to eliminate string using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions is probably the way to go. Here's an approach similar to what you wrote - we'll assume `input.txt` contains your input values, with `output.txt` as the export file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

infile = "input.txt"
outfile = "output.txt"
delete_list = [r'^.+\.sh\s*']

with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = re.sub(word, "", line)
            fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```py
import re
from io import StringIO

pattern = re.compile(r'^.+\.sh\s*')

data = '''\
papaya.sh   10
Moosumbi.sh 44
jackfruit.sh 15
orange.sh 11
banana.sh 99
grapes.sh 21
dates.sh 6
'''

# replace these two with your open(...) calls
fin = StringIO(data)
fout = StringIO()

for line in fin:
    fout.write(pattern.sub('', line))

# just for demonstration
print(fout.getvalue())
```

Comment: i wont be knowing the content of string data. only i would be knowing the string content will ended with .sh

Comment: As mentioned in the comment in the code, you are supposed to replace, e.g., `StringIO(data)` with your `open(infile)`. Surely you did not expect me to create a couple of files on my machine just for you.